# New Android Development for v4+ Should I use the Support Library?

Tags: android, android-support-library

Documentation says the support library helps backport new features to older version.  Should I use it if I am developing a new app designed for Android 4+ devices only?

Answer (score 2):

You use the Android Support package if:

- You are using something that is only in the Android Support package, like `ViewPager`, or
- The Android Support package contains a backport of something that you need

For an "app designed for Android 4+ devices only", the only backport I can think of is using the fragments backport *if* you need nested fragments. If you do not need nested fragments, the native version of fragments in API Level 11+ will work for you, without the need for the Android Support package.